# How to record current value and update it each step

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, if-statement

So I have a list here

```
Var = ['Level 3', 'Decrease', 'Increase', 'Same']
```

There are four levels: from 1 to 4. What I'm trying to do is, first it starts from level 3, then following the instructions in the list decrease down to level 2 and sets level 2 as the current level, then increase to level 3 again and set it as current level and follows the next instruction and so on.

I'm stuck on how to record the current level and update it at each step.

Here's what I have so far

```
if Var == 'Increase':
    if Starting_level == 'Level 1':
        # return level 2
    elif Starting_level == 'Level 2':
        # return level 3
    elif Starting_level == 'Level 3':
        # return level 4
    else:
        # return level 4

if Var == 'Decrease':
    if Starting_level == 'Level 1':
        # return level 1
    elif Starting_level == 'Level 2':
        # return level 1
    elif Starting_level == 'Level 3':
        # return level 2
    else:
        # return level 3

if Level == 'Same':
    if Starting_level == 'Level 1':
        # return level 1
    elif Starting_level == 'Level 2':
        # return level 2
    elif Starting_level == 'Level 3':
        # return level 3
    else:
        # return level 4
```

The above code only returns the first step, but because I haven't figured out how to update the current level after changes, it just stays there.

I feel like the solution is really simple, but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store your current level in `Starting_level` with each instruction. Also you don't require a `if` for `Var == 'Same'`. Try this:

```
def my_function(l1):
    Starting_level = l1[0]
    for Var in l1[1:]:

        if Var == 'Increase':
            if Starting_level == 'Level 1':
                Starting_level = 'Level 2'
            elif Starting_level == 'Level 2':
                Starting_level = 'Level 3'
            else:
                Starting_level = 'Level 4'
    
        if Var == 'Decrease':
            if Starting_level == 'Level 3':
                Starting_level = 'Level 2'
            elif Starting_level == 'Level 4':
                Starting_level = 'Level 3'
            else:
                Starting_level = 'Level 1'
        print(Starting_level)
    
Var = ['Level 3', 'Decrease', 'Increase', 'Same']
my_function(Var)

#OUTPUT
#Level 2
#Level 3
#Level 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the question they are only 4 levels(Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Level 4), with operations of 
Increase : incrementing the level
Decrease : decrementing the level
Same : no change

```
Var = ['Level 3', 'Decrease', 'Increase', 'Same']

def function(current_level, operation): #function for updating the current_level
    if(operation=='Same'): #need not to change
        return current_level
    k = int(current_level[-1]) #for knowing the current level number
    if(operation=='Increase'):
        k+=1
        if(k>4): #out of the range as per the question
            return -1
        return 'Level '+str(k)
    else:
        k-=1
        if(k<1):
            return -1 #out of the range as per the question
    return 'Level '+str(k-1)

current_level = Var[0]
for i in range(1,len(Var)):
    current_level = function(current_level,Var[i])
    if(current_level==-1): #as the level 4 or level 1 crossed no need of executing other operations
        break
print(current_level)
```

The current_level prints the last level after all operations, I returned -1 if it goes out of range(out of 4 levels), it could be easier to know.

I hope it might help you.
Let me know if they are any mistakes.